# If $b^3\mid c^2\qquad c,b\in \mathbb N$ prove that $b\mid c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> If $b^3\mid c^2\qquad c,b\in \mathbb N$ prove that $b\mid c$

---

**What I did:**

$b=p_1^{\alpha 1}\cdot p_2^{\alpha 2}\cdot \dots \cdot p_k^{\alpha k}$

$c=p_i^{\beta 1}\cdot p_{i+1}^{\beta 2}\cdot \dots \cdot p_{i+k}^{\beta j}$

Where $p$ is prime

Then $b^3$ and $c^2$ are:

$b^3=p_1^{3\alpha 1}\cdot p_2^{3\alpha 2}\cdot \dots \cdot p_k^{3\alpha k}$

$c^2=p_i^{2\beta 1}\cdot p_{i+1}^{2\beta 2}\cdot \dots \cdot p_{i+k}^{2\beta j}$

I am stuck here, how can I prove that?

Comment: So look at the powers of $p_1$ in $b^3$ and $c^2$. Since $b^3$ divides $c^2$ you must have $3\alpha_1\le 2\beta_1$. What are you trying to prove? That $\alpha_1\le\beta_1$.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider any individual prime factor $p_i^{3\alpha_i}$ of $b^3$.
Then, $p_i^{3\alpha_i}$ divides the corresponding prime factor in $c^2$, say, $p_i^{2\beta_i}$.

This is equivalent to saying that $3\alpha_i \leq 2\beta_i$, from which we see that $\alpha_i \leq \frac{2}{3} \beta_i \leq \beta_i$.

This means that $p_i^{\alpha_i}$ divides $p_i^{\beta_i}$ which divides $c$, which should give you the desired result, after repetition for each prime factor of $b$.